# Hibernate user and friend relationship add other column

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate

I want to make a friend system via hibernate, and I need to check user-friend's corresponding time when this user had related to other.

I hope table columns like following code:

```
table 1:
   int id;
   String name;

table 2:
   int user_id;
   int friend_id;
   Date startdate;
```

POJO code:

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Map<User,Date> friends;
}
```

Comment: You have to be more precise. It is good that you show your code, but what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need nothing more then JPA. Something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "friendship", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "friend_id")
    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private Map<Long, Date> friendshipMap;

    ... getters/setters ...

}
```

Comment: need more help : why I had generated a table "friendship" with column(user_id,start_date,**friends_KEY**)?

Comment: i had use @MapKeyJoinColumn and inverse to user's column "id".