# JPA Query ElementCollection key

Tags: java, jpa

I have an entity class called User with the variable username with an ElementCollection map to represent "friendship" between two users, mapped by the userId, the start date and the id of the friend. The code for that relation is as follows:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "friendship", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="userId"))
@MapKeyColumn(name = "friendId")
@Column(name = "startDate")
private Map<Integer, Date> friendShipMap;
```

I want to display the friends on a profile page for each user. I know I can just access the map via Java and get the ids (and find the usernames for the friends like that), but I'd like to use a custom @Query to get all the friends usernames for a given id. Somehow, the map is confusing me and I fail to find a proper statement for this.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Edit: To clarify, I would like to use a custom @Query statement for the following SQL statement:

```
select u.username from users u join friendship m on u.userId = m.friendId where m.userId = 1;
```

So I thought it would be basically like this:

```
@Query("SELECT u.username FROM users u join u.friendShipMap m on u.userId = key(m) where m.userId = :userId")
List<User> getFriends(@Param("userId") int userId);
```

But I can't use m.userId, it says "cannot dereference scalar collection element: userId".

The corresponding table looks like this:

```
userId | startDate |friendId
```

Comment: Can you show some code with which statements you tried?

Comment: Deleted them mostly, but what I basically need is the equivalent of "select u.username from users u join friendship m on u.userId = m.friendId where m.userId = 1;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `@Query`

```
@Query("select u.username from Users u inner join u.friendship f where f.friendId = :userId")
```

Make sure that you have an `association` between your entities `Users` and `Friendship`. Should be a `@OneToMany` relation I think.

And it should be in a `List<String>` instead of `Map`.

**EDIT:1**

If I understand it correctly, you will need another class `friendship`.

Maybe you need an embeddable class (`friendship`) described here.

http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/01/31/jpa-elementcollection-annotation/

Or you can create a new entity.

http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/elementcollection_hibernate_annotation

And this is also a good example:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection

Comment: I got the code for this from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663704/hibernate-user-and-friend-relationship-add-other-column with the map (id, date) to represent the start date for this relationship. Problem is, I either get no results from a query, or (using your Query) it's org.hibernate.QueryException: cannot dereference scalar collection element: friendId

Comment: Edited my original post just now, showing an example query which does not work. The map itself does not contain the userId but rather the friendId, hence why I can't reference it like this. I'm not sure how to continue from this code

Comment: There are only two classes really worth mentioning. The User Entity class has an id (userId), username and the @ElementCollection friendShipMap<Integer, Date>. The other is my interface extending a JpaRepository<User, Long> that provides my custom queries. Both are provided in my orginal post. There is no entity class by itself representing a friendship, because that's what I use the Collection Table for.

Comment: Was hoping for solving this via a query but in the end creating a seperate entity might be the best idea in the long run. Thanks for your time

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a solution without creating a new entity. But anyway, a new class makes your code also more readable and structured. I think you dont make a mistake with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need use with tansaction. Try it.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Query("SELECT u.username FROM users u join u.friendShipMap m on u.userId = key(m) where m.userId = :userId")
List<User> getFriends(@Param("userId") int userId);
```